# Unity Car Game display Kph Speed on Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display the car speed kph on the screen, but I only have 0kph and it is not working. Though I have this code. Any suggestions will be great thank you

[image]

```
public Text text;
private double Speed;
private Vector3 startingPosition, speedvec;

void Start () 
{
    startingPosition = transform.position;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    speedvec = ((transform.position - startingPosition) / Time.deltaTime);
    Speed = (int)(speedvec.magnitude) * 3.6; // 3.6 is the constant to convert a value from m/s to km/h, because i think that the speed which is being calculated here is coming in m/s, if you want it in mph, you should use ~2,2374 instead of 3.6 (assuming that 1 mph = 1.609 kmh)

    startingPosition = transform.position;
    text.text = Speed + "km/h";  // or mph

}
```

Any renewal / new edit of the code will be great. Thank you

Comment: Why are you casting to an (int) when you do magnitude * 3.6? Cast it to an int when you set the text.

Comment: `transform.velocity` ?

Comment: @RonBeyer Kindly Help me sir? I'm really new to this Unity Game ... any edit suggestions?

Comment: I don't really know .. I've just copied that code .. :( Honestly, this is my first project in unity to pass on school..

Comment: `Speed = speedvec.magnitude * 3.6;`, remove the cast.

Comment: does not change anything sir..

Comment: Do you have a rigidbody on the car? If you have one you can just get the current velocity using rigidbody.velocity.magnitude.

Comment: How can I do that sir? @SwiftingDuster

Comment: Add a Rigidbody component to your car if you don't already have one, then in your code: `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude`

Comment: Note that if you're not using rigidbody to move your car then you have to enable isKinematic and optionally disable use gravity for the rigidbody component in the inspector as well, other wise it'd interfere with your current movement code.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster is it in another script or I'll just insert to my current script?

Comment: Just change your current code to this: `text.text = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude + "km/h";`

Comment: It is an errord dddddd

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @SwiftingDuster it has an error saying **There is no Rigidbody attached to the text game**

Comment: Is this code you posted attached to the text and not the car? If thats the case then now I know where your problem is.

Comment: Yes it is attached to the text.. why sir?

Comment: When you call transform.position, you are trying to get the position of the text instead of the car. Since the text is always stationary on screen, your "Speed" will always be 0.

Comment: It is attached under the CarTiltControls

Comment: What is the solution sir?

Comment: Attach this code to your car instead, with the rigidbody, then drag your Speed indicator text gameobject from the hierarchy into the Text variable in the inspector

Comment: oh.h..... Thank you sir you are the man how can I make this question answered and just your answer will be marked as an answer?

Comment: 1 more thing sir,, what is the problem why my car even though it is not moving it is calculating its own speed?

Comment: Please make a new post if you have a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, OP apparently attached the code shown under the speed indicator Text GameObject instead of the Car. This caused the

> transform.position

and

> startingPosition

to always be the same value since the text object is a stationary UI element that doesn't move at all. (with the exception of world space UI objects)

You need to understand that transform.position returns the position of the GameObject the code is attached to. So if you attach it to the text, it will give you the position of the text and not the car.

The solution here is to attach the code to the Car instead, with a rigidbody, then assign the Text GameObject from the hierarchy to the speed indicator Text component variable through the inspector.

Lastly, with a rigidbody component you can simply get the speed with

```
text.text = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude;
```

Comment: What will I'll do to transdorm.position and startingPosition???  I've managed to run the numerical values but however it is on decimal places.. and how to fixed the values when the car is not moving I want it to become 0 instead of rounding the values?

Comment: Rounding the number seems the most legitimate solution to me. You might want to look at Mathf.Round. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html

Comment: Oh yeah Math.Round .. how can i implement it to the code sir? to finish my problem :(

Comment: Pretty sure the examples in the documentation I linked were sufficient to help you figure that out yourself. Documentation and trial and error is how you learn :)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using this code in my project and it works perfectly. Remembering that I added some options and made it more complete.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public enum SpeedUnit
{
    mph,
    kmh
}

public class SpeedOMeter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float currentSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private Text speedText;
    [SerializeField] private string previousText;
    [SerializeField] private SpeedUnit speedUnit;
    [SerializeField] private int decimalPlaces;
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        

        if (speedUnit == SpeedUnit.mph)
        {

            // 2.23694 is the constant to convert a value from m/s to mph.
            currentSpeed = (float)Math.Round(rb.velocity.magnitude * 2.23694f, decimalPlaces);

            //currentSpeed = (float)Math.Round((double)rb.velocity.magnitude * 2.23694f, 0);

            speedText.text = previousText + currentSpeed.ToString() + " mph";

        }

        else 
        {

            // 3.6 is the constant to convert a value from m/s to km/h.
            currentSpeed = (float)Math.Round(rb.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f, decimalPlaces);

            //currentSpeed = (float)Math.Round((double)rb.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f, 0);

            speedText.text = previousText + currentSpeed.ToString() + " km/h";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the future. Just wanted to let you know if you want something like this to work right out of the box, you can just use my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class realSpeedOMeter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float currentSpeed;
    public Text speedText;
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentSpeed = rb.velocity.magnitude * 2.23694f;

        speedText.text = currentSpeed.ToString() + "MPH";
    }
}
```